# if condition on array

Tags: android

if i have

```
int win[][] ={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{3,6,9},{1,5,9},{3,5,7}};
```

Can I put condition in this way?

```
if(((win[0][0]) && (win[0][1]) && (win[0][2]))||

            ((win[1][0]) && (win[1][1]) && (win[1][2]))||   

            ((win[2][0]) && (win[2][1]) && (win[2][2]))||

            ((win[3][0]) && (win[3][1]) && (win[3][2]))||

            ((win[4][0]) && (win[4][1]) && (win[4][2]))||

            ((win[5][0]) && (win[5][1]) && (win[5][2]))||

            ((win[6][0]) && (win[6][1]) && (win[6][2]))||

            ((win[7][0]) && (win[7][1]) && (win[7][2]))||

            ((win[8][0]) && (win[8][1]) && win[8][2])))
```

Comment: I don't see why not... though why you would do it that way? Have you considered looping over every group of 3?

Comment: why don't you try yourself first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is 8x3, means last element will be `win[7][2]`. So calling `win[8][0]` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception. If you correct this error, your code will work. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For a clearer version of this, why not try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if(win[i][0] && win[i][1] && win[i][2]) {
        doStuff();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's ok your solution, but i don't understand exactly how it works...for exemple if i=4, what will be the condition that will be verified?

Comment: You just answered your own question. When `i=4`, the `i`s in the if statement will be replaced with `4`s. Since your original condition was if ANY set of three are all true (because of your use of the || OR operator). Mine adds the break because, after one of the conditions are true (e.g. if `win[2][0] && win[2][1] && win[2][2]` evaluates to true), there is no reason to continue evaluating the remainder of the sets.

Answer (score -1):

If your aim is completely confuse the reader - you can

Comment: don't have enough reputation yet to make comments

Comment: Could you please explain why do you down vote this answer. Do you think it is ok to write such conditions?